# Bootstrap scale absolute image inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one row with 3 columns - image, text, image. I want the content to be centered vertically and the image to be outside the box. How to scale image on resize so the content look good on mobile? Because I want on mobile the image to bе above the text.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 850px;
}

.outer-box {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 55px 45px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.inner-box {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 45px 30px 45px 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -68px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nXbw78u.png" alt="" class="img">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
              <p class="text-uppercase">Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-1 col-md-2 text-right">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PzT4iyc.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you want the text to be at the bottom on mobile or between the images?

Comment: The last column is hidden on mobile.

Comment: I really dont understand what your really want!!!!

Comment: On mobile the text is upon the image because the image is position absolute, but how the text to be at the bottom and the image to be above and the image to be againt outside the box

Comment: ah great, you need to see media queries in css, which will let you apply different css on different screen sizes. see this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: ok, I can set position relative of the image on mobile

Comment: yes sure, that is what bootstrap uses to style elements differently on different screen sizes.